# when selecting an option from listby another listby dropdown appers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have displayed data in database as a table.on the top of this table i have listby and filterby dropdown. when selecting an option from listby another listby dropdown appers in codeigniter.

display.php (view)

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
    $sql="select * from feedback";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     ?>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function listby(str)
                            {
                            var xmlhttp;
                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                              {
                              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                              }
                            else
                              {
                              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                              }

                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                              {
                              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                {
                                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                                }
                              }
                            xmlhttp.open("GET","user1/ajax1?listby="+str,true);
                            xmlhttp.send();

                            }


                function filterby(str,limit)
                            {
                            var xmlhttp;
                            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                              {
                              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                              }
                            else
                              {
                              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                              }

                            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                              {
                              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                                {
                                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                                }
                              }

                            xmlhttp.open("GET","user1/ajax2?filterby="+str+"&limit="+limit,true);
                            xmlhttp.send();
                            }




            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                        <table >
                            <tr><td> List by:<select name="listby" id="select1" onchange="listby(this.value)">
                                    <option value="">select</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="10">10</option>
                                    <option value="20">20 </option>
                                    <option value="all">all </option>
                                    </select></td>

                                <td>    Filter by:<select name="filterby" onchange="filterby(this.value,document.getElementById('select1').value)">
                                    <option value="">select</option>
                                    <option value="php">php</option>
                                    <option value="dotnet">dotnet</option>
                                    <option value="java">java</option>
                                    <option value="seo">seo</option>
                                    </select></td>



                                <td><button>export to pdf </button></td>

                            </tr>
                        </table>    <br><br><br><br>



    <div id="mydiv">
    <table border="1" align="center" id="t1">

        <tr>

            <th>Sl.no</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>College</th>
            <th>Technologies interested in</th>
            <th>Mobile Apps development</th>
            <th>Feedback</th>
            <th>interested to study latest technologies</th></tr>
    <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
    ?>

     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['mobile'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['class'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['college'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['technologies_interested_in'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['mobile_apps_development'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['feedback'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['interested_to_study_latest_technologies'];?></td>


     </tr> 
     <?php  
            } 
     ?>

    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->


    ajax1.php



    <table border=0>
        <tr>

            <th>Sl.no</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>College</th>
            <th>Technologies interested in</th>
            <th>Mobile Apps development</th>
            <th>Feedback</th>
            <th>interested to study latest technologies</th></tr>


        <?php
             foreach($ajax1 as $row)
        {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['mobile'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['class'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['college'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['technologies_interested_in'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['mobile_apps_development'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['feedback'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['interested_to_study_latest_technologies'];?></td>

            </tr> 




        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>


     ajax2.php   



        <table border=0>
        <tr>

            <th>Sl.no</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Class</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>College</th>
            <th>Technologies interested in</th>
            <th>Mobile Apps development</th>
            <th>Feedback</th>
            <th>interested to study latest technologies</th>
        </tr>


        <?php
             foreach($ajax2 as $row)
        {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['mobile'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['class'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['college'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['technologies_interested_in'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['mobile_apps_development'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['feedback'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['interested_to_study_latest_technologies'];?></td>

            </tr> 




        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>




<!-- language: lang-css -->

    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class User_model1 extends CI_Model
        {
            public function __construct()
                {

                $this->load->database();
                }

            function get_student_details()
                {

                $query=$this->db->get('feedback');
                return $query->result_array();

                }

            function get_ajax1()
                {

                    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
                    $listby=$_GET['listby'];
                    $sql="select * from feedback order by name asc limit ".$listby;
                    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    return $query->result_array();
                }

            function get_ajax2()
                {

                        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','my_db');
                        $filterby=$_GET['filterby'];
                        $limit=$_GET['limit'];

                        if ($limit=="")
                            {
                            $sql="select * from feedback where technologies_interested_in='".$filterby."'";
                            }
                        else
                            {   
                            $sql="select * from feedback where technologies_interested_in='".$filterby."' limit ".$limit;
                            }

                        $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                        return $query->result_array();
                }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi Midhu, It's not clear what you're asking here. Is there a question you're trying to ask?

Comment: why you can't use **database library** of codeigniter instead of writing query from scratch? You are messing the view template as well. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html

Comment: i think this code also works in codeigniter

Comment: As @jogesh_pi said but codeigniter moved http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: i had changed the code to db library of codeigniter.bt my question is that is there any way to create this without ajax or is there any difference in writing ajax in codeigniter